# How to create a tensor from a float value?

Tags: tensorflow, neural-network, keras, loss-function

I'm using keras to build NN.
I need to make custom evaluation function (which I did but not completely).

Here is part of the code:

```
from keras import backend as K
...
def customized_loss(y_true, y_pred):
    loss = K.square(y_true - y_pred)
    return K.sum(loss)
...
model.compile(loss=customized_loss, optimizer='adam')
```

This part works perfectly but that's not really what I need.
I'd like to be able to return e.g. `0.123`
Currently, what is being returned is `K.sum(loss)` which is also just a value (wrapped in some tensor).
Whatever you write it down `0.123` or `[0.123]` or `[[0.123]]` or ...

So the question is how to transform float to tensor which will be accepted as a response in this custom loss function?

E.g. something like `return K.new_tensor(0.123)`
(also fyi I'm using tensorflow as backend)

**EDIT:**

I just realized that my idea makes no sense conceptually. I wanted to apply loss (amount) without providing any info on what the loss function is (i.e. what's its derivative) which is crucial for back propagation so it can know how to update weights.

Comment: I don't understand, you can't return a constant scalar from a loss function, it has to be symbolic. What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @Matias exactly... how to turn constant value into symbolic so it can be returned? When I return ```K.sum(loss)``` it's one value there wrapped in who knows what. So I just want to wrap some number into this "wrapper" so it can get returned.

Comment: But why return a constant value as loss? If you achieve this, you will get other errors as Keras will reject your loss function.

Comment: @matias-valdenegro Ok so how will then keras **not** reject my loss function? I have a custom loss calculation and in the end I end up with a number (which is the same as when I use default function like ```model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])```. The **only** difference is that this is calculated from ```y_true, y_pred``` with the help of functions like ```K.sum()``` which perserves it's "tensor-ness" and everything is ok. I just want to "tensorify" my value that I custom calculated. (it should be trivial except it's not for some reason)

Comment: No, that is not going to work, its not about being a tensor, its about being symbolic. Keras will compute the gradient of your loss function and that only works if you use the keras.backend functions. You MUST implement your loss with those functions (or with pure tensorflow if you like), else gradients cannot be computed and the network won't be trained.

Comment: @matias-valdenegro thank you for your input... I guess I need to study this more... do you think it would be easier for this kind of custom stuff to use some more low level libraries? (like pure TF or even lower like theano or caffe)

Comment: Well, whats the problem with using keras.backend? What exact loss are you trying to implement?

Comment: @matias-valdenegro Well I'm not going to lie, I am trying to do something crazy here :) but the main idea is that I calculate loss outside NN and apply it back to NN

Comment: @matias-valdenegro I just realized that my idea makes no sense conceptually. I wanted to apply loss (amount) without any info on what the loss function is (i.e. what's its derivative) which is crucial for back propagation so it can know how to update weights.

Comment: Good that you noticed, whatever custom computation can probably be done with Keras so its symbolic and differentiable.